# Need to one old url to new URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have convert old website to new website with URL Rewriting and It's working properly but as the seo manager, he asked to redirect 5 old urls to news urls because they are already on first pages in google search engines. He don't want any excuse and he want atleaset redirect 5 old url to new news. Please let me know how to redirect these pages to new urls.

**OLD URL:  [www.example.com/ViewCategory.php?CId=1211](http://www.example.com/ViewCategory.php?CId=1211)**

**New URL:  [www.example.com/Carrom-Boards.html](http://www.example.com/Carrom-Boards.html)**

Hope someone help me to fixed this.

Thanks & Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Well, sounds pretty straight forward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^CId=1211$
RewriteRule ^/?ViewCategory\.php$ /Carrom-Boards.html [QSD,R=301,L]
```

It is a good idea to start with a `R=302` *temporary* redireciton and only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as desired. That prevents nasty caching issues for users.

Comment: Dear arkasha,


Thanks for reply.


I have tried your above code but it is redirected on /Carrom-Boards.html?CId=1211
but i need redirect on Carrom-Boards.html only.


Because www.exmaple.com/Carrom-Boards.html?CId=1211 does not exits so it go back to index page.



Can you suggected how to redirect only www.exmaple.com/Carrom-Boards.html

Comment: Ah, indeed, missed that detail. I added the `QSD` flag in the answer. That should fix that detail.

Comment: So you have more query params than you stated in your question. And you dropped the `QSA` flag again. Why ever.